# How to save position of peaks detected in Java?

Tags: java, signal-processing

I have a peak detection algorithm for a ECG signal in Java, but it only gives the number of peaks detected. I have trouble figuring out how I can save the position of each peak in an array, which later can be plotted with the signal.

Here is my code, which only counts the peaks. Can someone help me alter it so it keeps the positions of each peak instead?

```
/** Peak detection
 * findePeaks() implements a general peak picking method for finding n local maxima in an array
 *   *  @param data input data
 *   *  @param peaks list of peak indexes
 *   *  @param width minimum distance between peaks
 *   *  @return The number of peaks found
 */
public static int findPeaks(double[] ecgMW, int[] peaks, int width) {
    int peakCount = 0;
    int maxp = 0;
    int mid = 0;
    int end = ecgMW.length;
while (mid < end) {
    int i = mid - width;
    if (i < 0)
        i = 0;
    int stop = mid + width + 1;
    if (stop > ecgMW.length)
        stop = ecgMW.length;
    maxp = i;
    for (i++; i < stop; i++)
        if (ecgMW[i] > ecgMW[maxp])
            maxp = i;
    if (maxp == mid) {
        int j;
        for (j = peakCount; j > 0; j--) {
            if (ecgMW[maxp] <= ecgMW[peaks[j-1]])
                break;
            else if (j < peaks.length)
                peaks[j] = peaks[j-1];
        }
        if (j != peaks.length)
            peaks[j] = maxp;
        if (peakCount != peaks.length)
            peakCount++;
    }
    mid++;
}
return peakCount;
}
```

Comment: You're taking in a paramter called peaks which is the index in the array of the peak

Comment: @johnny5 Huh, yeah I see that now. That is weird. It's a code example I got sent from a friend, so I don't know what she was doing there. Anyways, nevermind the code example - I need to figure out a way to find the peaks positions from the input data, with a minimum width of 85 samples. Can you help with that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample function to compute local min and max values. This should give you a starting point for your own implementation.
The below code is by no means complete or tested so be careful. Especially if you need to handle NaN or Inf values correctly you will need more logic to handle these special cases.

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] samples = { 1d, 2d, 2d, 3d, 0d, 5d, 6d, 5d, 0d };
        int width = 2;
        int[] peaks = new int[samples.length];
        int peakCount = findPeaks(samples, peaks, width);

        for (int i = 0; i < peakCount; i++) {
            int peakPosition = peaks[i];
            double peakValue = samples[peakPosition];
            System.out.printf("Peak %d\n", peakPosition);
        }

    }

    public static int findPeaks(double[] samples, int[] peaks, int minPeakDist) {
        assert samples.length == peaks.length;
        int peakIndex = 0;

        if (samples.length == 0) {
            return 0; // no samples -> no peaks
        } else if (samples.length == 1) {
            peaks[0] = 0;
            return 1;
        }
        double prev = samples[0];
        // indicates, if the next peak is a minimum or maximum
        boolean isFalling = samples[1] < samples[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < samples.length; i++) {
            final int oldI = i;
            if (prev == samples[i]) { // skip saddle points
                while (prev == samples[i] && i < samples.length) {
                    i++;
                }
                if (i >= samples.length) {
                    //TODO: maybe add last extremum
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (isFalling && prev < samples[i] // local min
                    || !isFalling && prev > samples[i]) { // local max
                isFalling = !isFalling;
                if (peakIndex == 0 || i - peaks[peakIndex - 1] >= minPeakDist) {
                    peaks[peakIndex++] = oldI - 1;
                }
            }
            prev = samples[i];
        }
        // TODO: maybe add last extremum
        return peakIndex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Jannik - I seem to have misunderstood the code. I am trying to implement it to a program of my own and I got this example from a friend, and have been trying to change it so it fits my own. So I don't actually have the "peaks" array.

Comment: @Heidi Hmm, ok, but then what is the problem you are facing? You could just use the code you posted or is it not working as expected?

Comment: It is not working - scratch the code example. I thought it would help, but see now that it is more confusing. My problem is that I have ECG data where I found the peaks using findpeaks function in MATLAB to save the positions of each peak in a array to use for further data analysis. Now I am trying to implement it in Java (which I am very new to) and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: This is a part of a Pan Tompkins algorithm, and ecgMW is the output of the moving window function. I want to use that as an input to the Peak Detection and the output should be an array with the sample numbers of each peak detected.

Comment: @Heidi I've updated my answer, maybe this helps you a bit. If you've got questions about the code let me know.